# Query optimization - Increasing Estimated Data Size

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization

One of my query (it's used to create report so it just contain: where's, join's and group by's) returned time out after ~20 min. Estimated Execution Plan showed me:

[image: fragment1]
[image]

This Hash Match probably means group by clause of my query. But something that was interesting for me is Estimated Data Size ~3TB, that is 10 times bigger than my database. After investigation I recognized part of query execution that higly increase this data transfer:

[image: fragment2]
[image]

but this Nested Loops has any impact in Query Cost due to Estimated Execution Plan.

This query is generated by Reporting Services and catched (I delete some unused part):

```
SET DATEFIRST 7
SELECT
    SUM([f_orders].[LORDEREDQTY_PU]) [QtyPU],
    SUM((((((((([f_orders].[DTRANSFERPRICE] + [f_orders].[DICSBASICORDERFEE]) + [f_orders].[DICSFREIGHTCHARGE]) + [f_orders].[DICSINSURANCEFEE]) + [f_orders].[DICSPACKINGFEE]) + [f_orders].[DICSFREETXTFEE]) + [f_orders].[DICSLOGISTICSFEE]) + [f_orders].[DICSPACKAGEPACKINGFEE]) * [A_ExchangeRates].[USDRate])) [TPinclChargesinUSDBudgetexchangerate],
    [f_orders].[LORDEREDQTY] [TotalQty],
    [dbo_D_ORDERADDRESS].[Countrycode] [Countrycode],
    [D_PRODUCT_NEW].[Framesize] [Framesize],
    [f_orders].[SZCUSSHORTNAME] [Customershortname],
    [f_orders].[SZCUSNO] [Customerno],
    [D_PRODUCT_NEW].[Generationcode] [Generationcode],
    [D_PU].[PU] [PU],
    [D_BALIDINFO].[SRU] [SRU],
    [D_WAREHOUSE].[Warehouse] [Warehouse],
    [f_orders].[DATE_OrderBookedatSU] [OrderbookedatSU],
    [f_orders].[DTCONFIRMEDDEL] [Confirmeddeliverydate],
    [D_PRODUCT_NEW].[MotorsProductType] [MotorsProductType],
    [f_orders].[SZORDERNO] [Orderno],
    [f_orders].[IORDERLINENO] [Orderlineno],
    [D_FRAMESIZE].[Framesize1] [Framesize1],
    [D_PRODGROUP].[Productgroup] [Productgroup],
    [D_PRODTYPE].[Producttype] [Producttype],
    [f_orders].[SZPRODNO] [Productno],
    [D_TYPEOFORDHAND].[Typeoforderhandling] [Typeoforderhandling],
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(LEN([f_orders].[SZVARIANTCODE]), 0) = 0 THEN CAST([f_orders].[IVARIANTCODENO] AS VARCHAR(255)) ELSE [f_orders].[SZVARIANTCODE] END [Variantcodeno],
    [f_orders].[IVARIANTIDX] [Variantindex],
    [f_orders].[DATE_OrderBookedatSU] [OrderbookedatSU1],
    [f_orders].[DATE_OrderBookedatSU] [OrderbookedatSU2]
FROM
[dbo].[f_orders] [f_orders]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [dbo_D_ORDERADDRESS].[SZCOUNTRYCODE] [Countrycode],
        [dbo_D_ORDERADDRESS].[ADDRESS_ORGID] [ADDRESS_ORGID]
    FROM
        (
            SELECT        CAST(1 AS numeric(38)) AS ID, CAST(CVCOUNTRY AS int) AS cvcountry, ADDRESS_ORGID, ORDERLINE_ORGID, ORDER_ORGID, CVADDRESSTYPE, IDWSOURCEID, 
                LORDERID, IORDERLINENO, SZNAME1, SZNAME2, SZNAME3, SZROAD1, SZROAD2, SZROAD3, SZPOSTCODE, SZTOWN, SZPHONE, SZFAX, SZCONTACTPERSON, 
                SZEMAIL, SZVATID, SZINVCUSNO, SZCOUNTRYCODE
            FROM            D_ORDERADDRESS_NEW
        ) [dbo_D_ORDERADDRESS]
) [dbo_D_ORDERADDRESS] ON ([f_orders].[DELADDRESS_ORGID] = [dbo_D_ORDERADDRESS].[ADDRESS_ORGID] OR [f_orders].[DELADDRESS_ORGID] IS NULL AND [dbo_D_ORDERADDRESS].[ADDRESS_ORGID] IS NULL)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [D_FRAMESIZE].[Framesize] [Framesize],
        [D_PRODUCT_NEW].[SZGENCODE] [Generationcode],
        [D_PRODTYPE].[MotorsProductType] [MotorsProductType],
        [D_PRODTYPE].[MotorsProdType] [MotorsProdType],
        [D_PRODUCT_NEW].[DWBOBJECTOID] [DWBOBJECTOID]
    FROM
        [dbo].[D_PRODUCT_NEW] [D_PRODUCT_NEW]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                [D_FRAMESIZE].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [Framesize],
                [D_FRAMESIZE].[VALUE] [VALUE]
            FROM
                [dbo].[D_FRAMESIZE] [D_FRAMESIZE]
        ) [D_FRAMESIZE] ON [D_PRODUCT_NEW].[CVFRAMESIZE] = [D_FRAMESIZE].[VALUE]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                [D_PRODTYPE].[SZMDPRODTYPE] [MotorsProductType],
                [D_PRODTYPE].[SZMDPRODTYPE] [MotorsProdType],
                [D_PRODTYPE].[VALUE] [VALUE]
            FROM
                [dbo].[D_PRODTYPE] [D_PRODTYPE]
        ) [D_PRODTYPE] ON [D_PRODUCT_NEW].[CVPRODTYPE] = [D_PRODTYPE].[VALUE]            
) [D_PRODUCT_NEW] ON ([f_orders].[DWPRDOID] = [D_PRODUCT_NEW].[DWBOBJECTOID] OR [f_orders].[DWPRDOID] IS NULL AND [D_PRODUCT_NEW].[DWBOBJECTOID] IS NULL)  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [D_BALIDINFO].[SZSOPREGION] [SRUSOPRegion],
        [D_BALIDINFO].[SZCOUNTRY] [SRUCountry],
        [D_BALIDINFO].[SZALTERNATEID] [SRU],
        [D_BALIDINFO].[SZALTERNATEID] [SZALTERNATEID],
        [D_BALIDINFO].[SZSOPREGION] [SOPRegion],
        [D_BALIDINFO].[DWBOBJECTOID] [DWBOBJECTOID]
    FROM
        [dbo].[D_BALIDINFO] [D_BALIDINFO]
) [D_BALIDINFO] ON [f_orders].[DWSALESRESPONSIBLEUNITOID] = [D_BALIDINFO].[DWBOBJECTOID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [D_PU].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [PU],
        [D_PU].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [PU2],
        [D_PU].[VALUE] [VALUE]
    FROM
        [dbo].[D_PU] [D_PU]
) [D_PU] ON [f_orders].[CVPU] = [D_PU].[VALUE]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [D_WAREHOUSE].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [Warehouse],
        [D_WAREHOUSE].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [Warehouse2],
        [D_WAREHOUSE].[VALUE] [VALUE]
    FROM
        [dbo].[D_WAREHOUSE] [D_WAREHOUSE]
) [D_WAREHOUSE] ON [f_orders].[CVWAREHOUSEID] = [D_WAREHOUSE].[VALUE]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [D_FRAMESIZE].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [Framesize1],
        [D_FRAMESIZE].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [FrameSize],
        [D_FRAMESIZE].[VALUE] [VALUE]
    FROM
        [dbo].[D_FRAMESIZE] [D_FRAMESIZE]
) [D_FRAMESIZE] ON [f_orders].[CVFRAMESIZE] = [D_FRAMESIZE].[VALUE]

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [D_PRODGROUP].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [Productgroup],
        [D_PRODGROUP].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [ProductGroup2],
        [D_PRODGROUP].[VALUE] [VALUE]
    FROM
        [dbo].[D_PRODGROUP] [D_PRODGROUP]
) [D_PRODGROUP] ON [f_orders].[CVPRODGROUP] = [D_PRODGROUP].[VALUE]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [D_PRODTYPE].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [Producttype],
        [D_PRODTYPE].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [ProductType2],
        [D_PRODTYPE].[VALUE] [VALUE]
    FROM
        [dbo].[D_PRODTYPE] [D_PRODTYPE]
) [D_PRODTYPE] ON [f_orders].[CVPRODTYPE] = [D_PRODTYPE].[VALUE]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [S_SECURITY].[Login_Name] [LoginName],
        [S_SECURITY].[Security_ID] [Security_ID]
    FROM
        [dbo].[S_SECURITY] [S_SECURITY]
) [S_SECURITY] ON [f_orders].[SECURITY_ID2] = [S_SECURITY].[Security_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [D_ORDERTYPE].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [OrderType],
        [D_ORDERTYPE].[VALUE] [VALUE]
    FROM
        [dbo].[D_ORDERTYPE] [D_ORDERTYPE]
) [D_ORDERTYPE] ON [f_orders].[CVORDERTYPE] = [D_ORDERTYPE].[VALUE]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [D_LINEORDERTYPE].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [LineOrderType],
        [D_LINEORDERTYPE].[VALUE] [VALUE]
    FROM
        [dbo].[D_LINEORDERTYPE] [D_LINEORDERTYPE]
) [D_LINEORDERTYPE] ON [f_orders].[CVLINEORDERTYPE] = [D_LINEORDERTYPE].[VALUE]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [A_ExchangeRates].[USDRate] [USDRate],
        [A_ExchangeRates].[CVCurrency] [CVCurrency],
        [A_ExchangeRates].[RateDate] [RateDate]
    FROM
        [dbo].[A_ExchangeRates] [A_ExchangeRates]
) [A_ExchangeRates] ON [f_orders].[CVCURRENCY] = [A_ExchangeRates].[CVCurrency] AND [f_orders].[DATE_OrderBookedatSU] = [A_ExchangeRates].[RateDate]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [D_TYPEOFORDHAND].[DESCRIPTIONEN] [Typeoforderhandling],
        [D_TYPEOFORDHAND].[VALUE] [VALUE]
    FROM
        [dbo].[D_TYPEOFORDHAND] [D_TYPEOFORDHAND]
) [D_TYPEOFORDHAND] ON [f_orders].[CVTYPEOFORDHAND] = [D_TYPEOFORDHAND].[VALUE]
    GROUP BY
[f_orders].[LORDEREDQTY], [dbo_D_ORDERADDRESS].[Countrycode], [D_PRODUCT_NEW].[Framesize],  
[f_orders].[SZCUSSHORTNAME], [f_orders].[SZCUSNO], [D_PRODUCT_NEW].[Generationcode],  
[D_BALIDINFO].[SRUSOPRegion], [D_BALIDINFO].[SRUCountry], [D_PU].[PU], [D_BALIDINFO].[SRU], [D_WAREHOUSE].[Warehouse], [f_orders].[DATE_OrderBookedatSU], [f_orders].[DTCONFIRMEDDEL], 
[D_PRODUCT_NEW].[MotorsProductType], [f_orders].[SZORDERNO], [f_orders].[IORDERLINENO], [D_FRAMESIZE].[Framesize1], 
    [D_PRODGROUP].[Productgroup], [D_PRODTYPE].[Producttype], [f_orders].[SZPRODNO],
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(LEN([f_orders].[SZVARIANTCODE]), 0) = 0 THEN CAST([f_orders].[IVARIANTCODENO] AS VARCHAR(255)) ELSE [f_orders].[SZVARIANTCODE] END,
    [f_orders].[IVARIANTIDX], [f_orders].[DATE_OrderBookedatSU], [f_orders].[DATE_OrderBookedatSU], D_TYPEOFORDHAND.Typeoforderhandling
```

1.Increasing Estimated Data Size by Nested Loop is normal and don't have any impact in performance?

2.I use about 20 grouping columns and it seems to have the biggest impact on Query Cost. It's possible to replace this Hash Match?

Comment: In "Query" select "Include Actual Execution Plan". In general that is better than the "Display Estimated Execution Plan". Also  this is a complex query and hard to pinpoint any problem without a mass of data to acid test. What I can recomend is: 1) Check indexes, 2) Check parameter sniffing, 3) Check parts of the query to find the bottlenecks

Comment: Btw the increase in the size of the mass of data in the processing flow is due some join. Example when you join two tables  with 3 and 7 rows and put a TRUE as the join condition you got 21 rows (more than double you have in both tables)

Comment: Why all the derived tables?  Why not just join directly?  Why the is null on a left join?  This negate the left group by [dbo_D_ORDERADDRESS].[Countrycode].

Comment: @jean 1)But why this rows multiplication don't have impact in cost? 2)The most costly part is caused by aggregation - how to optimize it?

Comment: @Frisbee I didn't write this query - it's generated by Reporting Services. I catched it using DMV.

Comment: You can't change the query?  Then what is the purpose of the question?

Comment: Sure it impacts! But you must find why that is happening and a good way is to check that little monster in smaller parts. It's not uncommon to one aggregation to produce a result and a developer try to apply this result in a join and ending producing a "cartesian product" because the aggregation impaired the correctness of the join condition. Those kind of error is subtle and maybe is the point here. You can check for it

Comment: @Frisbee I can, but I have many queries like this.

Comment: Report Services Generated? Well someone designed it in some tool. As rule of thumb more the graphical the tool less the developer knows what is happening in the DB and less optimzed is the query is. If you are not able to change this query you can try optimize indexes or buy a bigger server. But by the price a good server is I bet you boss can tell you to redesign the report to use a nice handwritted query

Comment: So you have a lot.  Start with cleaning this up.  If you are not going to optimize the posted query then why post the question?

Comment: @jean Yes, using Report Builder. How to use indexes to deal with Hash Match (Aggregate)? As I know indexes can only help with joins and where.

Comment: @Frisbee To sum up. I have many reports like that so I need "macro solution" for all, because optimizing each query will be too time-consuming. I recognised higly increasing data flow part and I wonder maybe this is the part which I should focus (1 question) and how to decrease cost of aggregation (2 question)?

Comment: How are you going to write a macro if you don't know how to optimize one?    You should focus on cleaning up the query.   Join to derived is not efficient.

Comment: @Kulis Indexes can help aggregates, examples: index the column Criteria to match (the BY part of the aggregate) also if a query (aggregate or not) uses a covering index it ill skip the table. But if you are not able or willing to rewrite that query your odds in successfully improve that query drops a lot. By experience rewriting and tunning a bad writted +20min query can drastically improve it. Most times to less than 1 min. In rare cases to seconds.

Comment: I have found that complicated queries like this can run a lot faster if broken up into smaller units and using temporary tables to hold the intermediate data. I have done this and dropped query times from 20+ minutes down to seconds, especially with cross-server joins.

Comment: Without the entire Actual Execution Plan, it's really difficult to see everything going on but, I can guarantee your having issues with statistics.  I agree with @Frisbee on the derived tables, you have zero statistics for those derived tables.  Where possible, you really need to either join directly to the orders table or create temp tables that join to the orders table to take advantage of statistics.  Also there is not a single predicate.  Statistics matter and there is little in this query to take advantage of them.  This really needs to be refactored.

Comment: @MikeZalansky It is not just statistics.  You lose access to indexes.

Comment: @Frisbee, totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

ok your query looks fairly complex and is most likely confusing the optimiser, perhaps look at statistics to see if you can help the optimiser by using full scan. Consider using temp tables to stage the nested joins so you stage just the columns you need. Also consider adding indexes for this on the main table f_orders to reduce the table scan.